# How does umbraco template know which document to get property value from when two docs of same type exist?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I setup a simple document type with **two content pages**,a **single** template, and a **single** document type.

It works but what is puzzling me is how does umbraco know **which** content page to get the property value from? They are both the same document type. A screenshot below with my two pages shows the setup. How can I tell umbraco to pick the second page instead of the first one? 
Thank you

[image: umbraco setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all a `Document Type` is just a class definition which contains a set of properties.

Of a `Document Type` you can create as many content pages you want.

If you create a new content page you will see that each node has a `Properties` tab which contains default Umbraco properties like Id, Guid, Created By, ...

But it contains also a template propertie, which indicated which html it needs to display in the frontend.

And it also has a property url which is the link to your page.

Now when you go to one of your 2 pages ( url ) then Umbraco using its builtin routing to know what content node it is and of which document type.

Then using the identifier it takes the correct value.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. For the second part of the question, i.e. how to change the default URL, I added a umbracoUrlAlias text/string property to the document and was able to simply add the desired url there, worked great.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!